# redefinition of 'std::__is_integer<char>' when build Opcode in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

When I built [Opcode](http://www.codercorner.com/Opcode.htm) in Xcode, I get the following error. I use C++ 11 and libstdc++ in Xcode 5.1. It seems the problem of template specialisation, but I don't know why.

```
In file included from /Users/chogri/Code/works/abc/Sources/external/opcode/src/Opcode.cpp:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:45:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:72:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:168:12: error: redefinition of 'std::__is_integer<char>'
    struct __is_integer<char>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Don't use the version of libstdc++ that comes with the OS on Mac (especially not in C++11 mode). It's an ancient version. Use libc++.

Comment: After using libc++ in C++11 mode, there are other errors including this error. 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:1930:44: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__rep, std::__1::allocator<char>, '\x00', '\x00', '\x01'>'

Comment: Sounds like you (or the library) forgot some includes.